# php rowCounter() function to login

Tags: php

I'm trying to create my first web site using html, css, js and php. I have a problem with a php function:

```
public function doLogin($login,$pass,$conn)
{

    $req="SELECT login,password FROM client WHERE login='"+$login+"'";
    $liste=$conn->query($req);
    if($liste->rowCount()==1)
    {
       return true;
    }

}
```

It's supposed to be used in the login but I get this message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\test\methode.php on line 56

Comment: Well the query didn't work so it returned `false` which you put in `$liste`. That's why it says **Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object** because it's a boolean and not an object.

Comment: From the documentation: "*For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement*" -- also mixing JavaScript and PHP here (which is why the query fails, and you just assume it's working): `'"+$login+"'"` those `+` are not for PHP (it's for JavaScript), use `.` to combine strings instead. You should also look into prepared statements, since you're using an API that supports it. http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/4535200

Answer (score 0):

regardless of any consideration about injection, take note that in php you must use . and not + concatenate strings.
I.e.:

```
$req="SELECT login,password FROM client WHERE login='"+$login+"'";
```

should be

```
$req="SELECT login,password FROM client WHERE login='".$login."'";
```